# if a gas grill's push-button battery-operated igniter is clicking, but grill doesn't light

Tags: gas-burner

My grill is: the `Weber Q 1200`

If an outdoor gas grill's push-button battery-operated igniter is making clicking sounds, but grill doesn't light, what clues does that give me?

I think it means that the module is mostly working, the battery is working, but somehow there's no flame produced. Is this correct?

Also: what's the first thing I should try to fix?

---

Update (how it was solved):

- the accepted answer was very helpful to me because it broke down for me that the most likely culprit was probably food drippings in the area where the igniter spark operates.
- So, I lifted the grating, scraped off any rust/drippings in that area, and my igniter started working again.
- There wasn't anything wrong with the igniter. It was just that the gas wasn't coming out of the nearest hole in the gas pipe because that hole was rusted over and blocked by food drippings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the wire from the button to where it ends, somewhere near the burner.

In theory, it will be clipped a specific distance from the burner so that a spark will jump between it and the burner to ignite the gas.

In practice, it could be covered with food drippings or could have become detached from where it is supposed to be, or it could be thoroughly corroded.

If you can clean it and make sure it is attached in the right place, it should work okay again.

But more likely there's not much you can do that will make a permanent fix, and you'll end up using a hand-lighter to ignite the flame.